# How to make the spring mvc controller to update multiple tables?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc web and I want to perform some tables' update. When I click on the link, I have to wait the task to be completed in order to perform another task. Each link is correspond to different table, how would I improve this if I want to speed up process.
[image]

controller class

```
public class AdminController{   
    @Autowired
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;  

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    public HashMap<Long, ICollector> collectors;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/config/configcollectlist",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getConfigCollectist(ModelMap model) 
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<DbConfigCollect> configCollects = (List<DbConfigCollect>)session.createCriteria(DbConfigCollect.class).list();
        session.close();

        model.addAttribute("configCollects", configCollects);
        return "admin/config/configcollectlist";       
    } 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/config/configcollectorlist",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getConfigCollectorist(ModelMap model) 
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<DbConfigCollector> configCollectors = (List<DbConfigCollector>)session.createCriteria(DbConfigCollector.class).list();
        session.close();

        model.addAttribute("configCollectors", configCollectors);
        return "admin/config/configcollectorlist";     
    } 
}
```

task class

```
public class CollectorPropertyRED_UK_PPD implements ICollector{ 
    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void collect(DbConfigCollect inDbConfigCollect)
    {
        taskExecutor.execute(new CollectorPropertyRED_UK_PPDTask(sessionFactory, inDbConfigCollect));
    }
}

public class CollectorPropertyRED_UK_PPDTask extends CollectorTaskBase {
    public enum COLLECT_PARAMETER_PAPER_COREACUK_FILE {
        FILE_INPUT,
    };

    public final static String FILE_SUFFIX_CSV = ".csv";

    public CollectorPropertyRED_UK_PPDTask(SessionFactory sessionFactory,
            DbConfigCollect inDbConfigCollect) {
        super(sessionFactory, inDbConfigCollect);
    }

    public void run() {
        String[] parameters = this.myDbConfigCollect.getParameters().split(";");

        // load file
        File[] sourceFiles = new File(
                parameters[COLLECT_PARAMETER_PAPER_COREACUK_FILE.FILE_INPUT
                        .ordinal()]).listFiles();

        int totalCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceFiles.length; i++) {

            if (sourceFiles[i].getName().endsWith(FILE_SUFFIX_CSV)) {
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                String fileName = sourceFiles[i].getName();

                CSVReader reader = null;
                int count = 0;
                try {
                    reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(sourceFiles[i]));
                    String[] currLine = null;
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

                    while ((currLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                        String unique_id = currLine[0];
                        ++count;
                        updateToDb(sessionFactory,currLine);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Updated:
I have tried to follow the [async request guide](http://shengwangi.blogspot.hk/2015/09/asynchronous-spring-mvc-hello-world.html), but it won't work as expected. When I refresh the browser using the same url, I get the response of the controller immediately, but the doSlowWork() method need to wait until the previous task has been finished. here are my code.

controller class

```
@Autowired
HelloService helloService;
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminController.class);
@RequestMapping(value ="/helloAsync", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Callable<String> sayHelloAsync() {
    System.out.println("Entering controller");

    Callable<String> asyncTask = new Callable<String>() {

      @Override
      public String call() throws Exception {
        return helloService.doSlowWork();
      }
    };

    return asyncTask;
  }
```

asynctask class

```
@Service
public class HelloService {
  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloService.class);

  public String doSlowWork() {

      Random rand = new Random();

      int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;

      System.out.println("start: "+n);

    try {
      Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("end: "+ n);
    return "index";       // return view's name
  }
}
```

Output

```
INFO    2016-11-16 15:49:37,706 [http-bio-8080-exec-16] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.AdminController  - Entering controller
INFO    2016-11-16 15:49:37,710 [http-bio-8080-exec-16] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.AdminController  - Leaving controller
INFO    2016-11-16 15:49:37,720 [taskExecutor-1] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.HelloService  - Start  slow work
INFO    2016-11-16 15:49:38,201 [http-bio-8080-exec-13] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.AdminController  - Entering controller
INFO    2016-11-16 15:49:38,202 [http-bio-8080-exec-13] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.AdminController  - Leaving controller
INFO    2016-11-16 15:49:38,975 [http-bio-8080-exec-15] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.AdminController  - Entering controller
INFO    2016-11-16 15:49:38,976 [http-bio-8080-exec-15] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.AdminController  - Leaving controller
INFO    2016-11-16 15:49:47,721 [taskExecutor-1] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.HelloService  - finish slow work
INFO    2016-11-16 15:49:47,723 [taskExecutor-1] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.HelloService  - Start  slow work
INFO    2016-11-16 15:49:57,724 [taskExecutor-1] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.HelloService  - finish slow work
INFO    2016-11-16 15:49:57,726 [taskExecutor-1] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.HelloService  - Start  slow work
INFO    2016-11-16 15:50:07,726 [taskExecutor-1] com.exbidata.db.mvc.controller.admin.HelloService  - finish slow work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Spring asynchronous request processing feature instead,

With Servlet 3.0 the async support is added. First you need to enable the async support in your web.xml as follows,

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet- class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <!-- turn on async support for servlet -->
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

From your existing controller handler method instead of returning string return callable

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/config/configcollectlist",method =   RequestMethod.GET)
  public Callable<String> getConfigCollectist(ModelMap model) 
  {
    Callable<String> asyncTask = new Callable<String>() {

       @Override
       public String call() throws Exception {

       Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
       List<DbConfigCollect> configCollects = (List<DbConfigCollect>)session.createCriteria(DbConfigCollect.class).list();
       session.close();
       model.addAttribute("configCollects", configCollects);

       return "admin/config/configcollectlist"; 
     }
   };

  return asyncTask;
 }
```

Also you need to configure spring application context for async support. (I have mentioned XML based configuration)

```
<mvc:annotation-driven> 
   <mvc:async-support default-timeout="30000" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
<!-- modify the parameters of thread pool -->
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
  <property name="corePoolSize" value="5"/>
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"/>
  <property name="queueCapacity" value="10"/>
  <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="120"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I just updated my code, would you please have a look

Comment: Can you please provide your log/error which indicates the current thread waiting for previous one to complete?

Comment: Okay, this output is generated of me pressing the refresh button few times.

Comment: I forgot to add the log in controller, I added back now

Comment: @peter logs are too asynchronous so you might get impression of thread is blocked also I hope approach i put solves your issue. please accept.

Comment: Finally it works. I was so careless that I didn't set the corePoolSize from 1 to 5. I dont know why without adding the Callable, it still works with the original code.